# Could anyone help to describe the two different priority ceiling protocols, ICPP and OCPP?

Tags: real-time, scheduling

As far as I know, for ICPP, a process can acquire the ceiling priority as soon as it accesses the shared resources. But for OCPP, when and how can the process with accessing to shared resources acquire the ceiling priority? Is it when ANY other process tries to access any shared resources? But which priority can it acquire then?

Answer (score 0):

> But for OCPP, when and how can the process with accessing to shared resources acquire the > ceiling priority?

In OCPP the process only gets its priority boosted (set to the ceiling of the resource or to the priority of a higher-than-ceiling waiting thread) if it is blocking a higher task from executing.

From [www2.in.tum.de/hp/file?fid=319](http://www2.in.tum.de/hp/file?fid=319)

> OCPP has an added restriction compared to ICPP that a process can lock
>   a resource only if its dynamic priority is higher than the priority
>   ceiling of ANY resource currently locked by other processes.

This last property comes from the fact that OCPP doesn't set the priority of the holding task right away after acquisition it can be subject to priority inversion (being postponed by a task that is lower in its original non-boosted priority).

These problems are solved in ICPP.